# Cannot set GPIO pins on banana pi-m3 to output (python)

Tags: python, gpio, banana-pi

I recently aquired a banana pi-m3 and after a very rough start I managed to get it to boot. I have now come across another problem being that whatever I try, I cannot get the gpio pins to say OUT rather than IN and I get no errors. I am using python, rpi.gpio (for banana pi), and my power supply is fine. This is my test code, designed to make an LED blink:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    GPIO.output(26, True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(26, False)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I have tried GPIO.setmode(BOARD) and using each method, checked all the pins for that output while the program was running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use sata like me. Stay at bananapi may be a better choise. Having considered for a long time, here are three ways to solve this problem.
If you are good at C, you can write your program in C then wrap it as a library for python.
If you can write both C and python, you can try to fork wiringpi2 then modify it, it seems that wiringpi2 is just a wrapped library of wiringpi C library.
If you are good at python and don't want to write  C code, you can try to call system command provided by wiringpi by import "os" library

So here's a note for you, me and others: if any one who want to buy or already buy a bananapi for development, remember bananapi is NOTHING LIKE raspberrypi, from hardware to software, and in fact bananapi is completely  incompatible with raspberrypi. Anyone who want to purchase bananapi may have to do more work on driver, you can learn more, but cost lots of time.

And REMEMBER: DO NOT open source your own driver for bananapi or other "xxPi" from China or your code may appeared in theirs library or products which not open source.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a library for bpi m1. This library hasn't been update any more and may not support bpi  m3. Unfortunately the official bpi's github also hasn't update python gpio library for m3, only c library, so it may unable to control gpio with python on bpi m3, and it maybe a mistake to buy  bananapi because of very very bad support. Btw official github is BPI-SINOVOIP.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I'm going to return my banana and get a raspberry.